# onActivityResult: resultCode always returns 2

Tags: android, android-fragments, braintree, onactivityresult, start-activity

I am trying to integrate BrainTree into my app, but I'm having some issues with `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`. I have already properly retrieved a *clientToken* but for some reason I'm always receiving a *resultCode* of 2 in `onActivityResult`. In addition I also get this in my Logs:

> I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class

Any idea what's going on? Here's some snippets of my code in case it helps:

This is the *onClick* method in my fragment.

```
void onPaymentClick() {
   PaymentRequest paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest().clientToken("<client_token>");
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(paymentRequest.getIntent(storeOrderActivity), 1);
    }
}
```

And this is the *onActivityResult* code in my activity. *(`PostOrder` is the the function that's supposed to run once Braintree sends a nonce back to me, but this doesn't even run since I get a resultCode of 2)*

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce = data.getParcelableExtra(
                    BraintreePaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT_METHOD_NONCE
            );
            PostOrder.postOrder(this, fabCartAdapter.getCart(), paymentMethodNonce.getNonce());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resultCode==2` is reserved for [`BRAINTREE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/master/Drop-In/src/main/java/com/braintreepayments/api/BraintreePaymentActivity.java#L75):

> The payment method flow halted due to a resolvable error (authentication, authorization, SDK upgrade required). The reason for the error will be returned in a future release.

Probably you need to double check if the SDK is set it up correctly.